# Python aborts as soon as I import a package

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm using Python 3.4.3 on WSL (Ubuntu 14.04). Everything was working fine previously. However, after updating all my pip packages and Ubuntu packages, Python aborts whenever I run `import theano`. If a Python script has only that one line or if I run it in the REPL, it still aborts. It also aborts if I import `pandas` or `keras`, but not `numpy`, `scipy`, or `nltk`.

When I tried using GDB to debug it, I got this:

```
Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
0x00007ffffee46c37 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6)
    at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:56
56      ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: No such file or directory.
```

And the stacktrace:

```
#0  0x00007ffffee46c37 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6)                               
    at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:56                                    
#1  0x00007ffffee4a028 in __GI_abort () at abort.c:89                                
#2  0x00007fffff1e7060 in __free_stacks (limit=limit@entry=41943040)                 
    at allocatestack.c:287                                                           
#3  0x00007fffff1e713f in queue_stack (stack=0x7ffff93f0700) at allocatestack.c:310  
#4  __deallocate_stack (pd=pd@entry=0x7ffff93f0700) at allocatestack.c:771           
#5  0x00007fffff1e8419 in __free_tcb (pd=pd@entry=0x7ffff93f0700)                    
    at pthread_create.c:226                                                          
#6  0x00007fffff1e9694 in pthread_join (threadid=140737375045376, thread_return=0x0) 
    at pthread_join.c:113                                                            
#7  0x00007ffffc7fc977 in blas_thread_shutdown_ () from /usr/lib/libopenblas.so.0    
#8  0x00007ffffeed49c2 in __libc_fork ()                                             
    at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/../fork.c:95                           
#9  0x0000000000572b3a in ?? ()                                                      
#10 0x00000000004866fb in PyEval_EvalFrameEx ()                                      
#11 0x000000000048e45b in PyEval_EvalCodeEx ()                                       
#12 0x000000000048a673 in PyEval_EvalFrameEx ()                                      
#13 0x000000000048f2df in ?? ()                                                      
#14 0x000000000053493d in ?? ()                                                      
#15 0x00000000004f14fa in PyObject_Call ()                                           
#16 0x0000000000507a0a in ?? ()                                                      
#17 0x0000000000535916 in ?? ()                                                      
#18 0x000000000048a487 in PyEval_EvalFrameEx ()                                      
#19 0x000000000048a19d in PyEval_EvalFrameEx ()                                      
#20 0x000000000048a19d in PyEval_EvalFrameEx ()                                      
#21 0x000000000048e45b in PyEval_EvalCodeEx ()                                       
#22 0x000000000048f15b in PyEval_EvalCode ()                                         
#23 0x0000000000566c1f in ?? ()                                                      
#24 0x000000000048b98c in PyEval_EvalFrameEx ()                                      
#25 0x000000000048e45b in PyEval_EvalCodeEx ()                                       
#26 0x000000000048a673 in PyEval_EvalFrameEx ()                                      
#27 0x000000000048a19d in PyEval_EvalFrameEx ()                                      
#28 0x000000000048a19d in PyEval_EvalFrameEx ()                                      
#29 0x000000000048a19d in PyEval_EvalFrameEx ()                                      
#30 0x000000000048a19d in PyEval_EvalFrameEx ()                                      
#31 0x000000000048f2df in ?? ()                                                      
#32 0x00000000004f14fa in PyObject_Call ()                                           
#33 0x00000000004b0a92 in _PyObject_CallMethodIdObjArgs ()                           
#34 0x00000000004b0eab in PyImport_ImportModuleLevelObject ()                        
#35 0x000000000051bca7 in ?? ()
```

I'm not familiar enough with GDB and Python to debug further.

I tried reinstalling Python and the pip packages, but it still aborts. What could be wrong?

Comment: Try using a virtual environment. (I know it's not the correct solution)